# ENTER key pressing event not working dojo 1.10

Tags: javascript, dojo

This is not working when I press the Enter key

```
var loginContent = new ContentPane({
    id: 'lgncontent',
    content: loginboxes,
    onKeyPress: loginKeyPress
});

function loginKeyPress(evt) {
    require(["dojo/keys", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on"], function (keys, dom, on) {
        on(dom.byId("lgncontent"), "keypress", function (evt) {
            switch (evt.charOrCode) {
                case keys.ENTER:
                    console.log('ENTER!');
                    sendCred(lForm.getValues());
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED
instead of the function, I had to add the following lines after dlg definition:

```
var btnClick = dlg._onKey = function(evt) {
 key = evt.keyCode;
 if (key == dojo.keys.ENTER) {
  sendCred(lForm.getValues());
 }
}
```

Comment: do not forget to put `var` keyword before the `key` variable (i.e `var key = evt.keyCode;`), preventing the variable becoming global.